replaceAll not working y API Gateway Gateway Response
I have an API Gateway set up with request body validation.
I want to customize the response when there is an error in the validation.
I modified the Gateway Response for Bad request body and set the response template to:
{
  "message": $context.error.messageString,
  "errors": "$context.error.validationErrorString.replaceAll(\"\\\"\", \"\")"
}

My goal is to remove the \" group of characters from the response message, which is:
([object has missing required properties ([\"prop1\",\"prop2\",\"propN\"])])
But when I perform the request, what I get as response is:
{
    "message": "Invalid request body",
    "errors": "(\"\\\"\", \"\")"
}

I supose that I have some kind of syntax error, but I can't get any feedback from API Gateway about what is wrong with the template or how to fix it.
Thank you very much!
